# Jquery Cookie Read and Set

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I am trying to have it look to see if the cookie exists and if not fade in. Then if the user clicks the close button it fades out. What am I doing wrong?

Jquery

```
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie("demoCookie") == null) {
        $("#headerFactInfo").fadeIn();
    };

    $("#headerFactInfoClose").click(function() {
        $("#headerFactInfo").fadeOut();
        $.cookie( 'demoCookie', '1',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );  
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="headerFactInfo">The Great Add <a href="" id="headerFactInfoClose" >Close</a></div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's happening or *not* happening?

Comment: Non of it is working, it wont set the cookie, it wont fade in and as far as I can tell its not reading the cookie.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your JS console? And, perhaps this is obvious but just in case: did you remember to include the JS file for the cookie plugin (it's not a core part of jQuery)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wPP6Y/

I made only 2 modifications:

**CSS**

```
/* It's hard to tell whether it's fading in
 * or not if it's always visible
 */
#headerFactInfo {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#headerFactInfoClose").click(function() {
    $("#headerFactInfo").fadeOut();
    $.cookie( 'demoCookie', '1',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );

    return false; // Prevent the link to actually follow the href
});
```

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or Chrome's [developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html), or your favorite browser's equivalent to play around with the cookie.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to put return false;

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, cookie check is not working then, try:

```
$(function() {
     var Cooki = $.cookie('demoCookie');

    if (Cooki == null) {
        $("#headerFactInfo").fadeIn();
    }

    $("#headerFactInfoClose").click(function() {
        $("#headerFactInfo").fadeOut();
        $.cookie( 'demoCookie', '1',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );  
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm curious why you think storing the function return in a variable before the comparison would make a difference? (Or is there some other change in your code that I'm not seeing?)

Comment: As of right now non of it works, it does not fade in, it does not create the cookie and as far as I can tell it does not read if there is a cookie but this could be just because I cant create a cookie. So I dunno what I am doing wrong.